# Counting Disk Intersections using TreeSet

Tags: java

I'm trying a demo problem of Codility, before I take the real test as part of a job application. One of the demos they have is a problem involving counting the number of disk intersections, for an array of disks.

Task description is

> Given an array A of N integers, we draw N discs in a 2D plane such
>   that the I-th disc is centered on (0,I) and has a radius of A[I]. We
>   say that the J-th disc and K-th disc intersect if J ≠ K and J-th and
>   K-th discs have at least one common point. Write a function: class
>   Solution { public int number_of_disc_intersections(int[] A); } that,
>   given an array A describing N discs as explained above, returns the
>   number of pairs of intersecting discs.

You can view the test [here](http://codility.com/c/intro/demoRHS3WV-H4J).

There are somewhat obvious O(n^2) time complexity solutions, but the aim is for O(n*log(n)).

I've come up with this, which works on any examples I've provided, and the simple test case given by codility ( [1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0] ), but Codility tells me it fails on most others but I can't quite see why.

It should certainly be O(n log n) as adding each of n disks to a TreeSet is log n, and then we walk through each disks, with only the O(1) operation TreeSet.headSet().

```
import java.util.*;

class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
  long edge;
  int index;

  Circle (long e, int i){
    edge = e;
    index = i;
  }

  long getRightAssumingEdgeIsLeft(){
    return (long)(2*index - edge + 1);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Circle other){
    return Long.valueOf(edge).compareTo(other.edge);
  }
}

class Solution {
  public int number_of_disc_intersections ( int[] A ) {
    int N = A.length;
    if (N<2) return 0;
    int result = 0;

    SortedSet<Circle> leftEdges  = new TreeSet<Circle>();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      leftEdges.add( new Circle( (long)(i-A[i]), i ) );
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (Circle c : leftEdges) {
      long rightEdge = c.getRightAssumingEdgeIsLeft();
      Circle dummyCircle = new Circle (rightEdge, -1);
      SortedSet<Circle> head = leftEdges.headSet(dummyCircle);
      result +=  head.size() - counter;
      if (result > 10000000) return -1;
      counter++;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this question belongs more to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A different algorithm (`O(N log N)`):

This bad drawing of the scenario:

[image]

Can be translated into a list of ranges: (not exactly the same scenario)

Fig. 2
[image]

O(N log N):  We first sort the markers, taking care that green markers appear before red ones if we want to count tangent discs as overlaps.

O(N): We scan from left to right, with `total` initially `= 0` and `overlaps` initially `= 0`. Every time we hit a green marker, `total += 1`, and at every red marker, `total -= 1`. Additionally, at each green marker, `if total > 0, then overlaps += total`.

The black numbers in Fig. 2 are `total` at each step; orange is `overlaps`.

Then `overlaps` should be the answer.

See a crude implementation here: http://ideone.com/ggiRPA

Comment: This is more elegant, and less confusing. And it works! I've put a Java implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/RcMNVNUr), for those curious. The only slight adjustments that I increment `total` after adding it to overlaps ("this new circle overlaps with `total` existing circles. And now there is a new circle to think about"). And then the `if total>0` condition isn't necessary because `total` can no longer be negative. There is probably a slightly better way to go through the queues than peeking and polling though.

Comment: please add input and make ranges from those inputs to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way...

1. Create 2 arrays of N elements (leftEdge, rightEdge).
2. For each element calculate left and right edge (index -/+ value) and set it in arrays.
3. Sort arrays.
4. For each element in rightEdge array loop through leftEdge array to find first greater or equal element. Save number of remaining elements and current index. For next element start loop from saved index...

This way we really loop through each sorted array only once, so algorithm's complexity is O(N log N).

Answer (score 2):

This method does not require any special classes such as circles or complex containers such as PriorityQueue or TreeSet. Simple integer arrays are all that are needed. It is O(N * logN). The language is Java.

```
public int numberOfDiscIntersections(int [] A) {
    // 0 <= A.length <= 100,000
    // 0 <= A[i] <= 2147483647
    int [] leftEdge = new int[A.length];
    int [] rightEdge = new int[A.length];

    int maxLength = 100000;
    // maxLength is used to prevent integers > 2147483647
    // and integers < -2147483647
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        leftEdge[i] = i - A[i];
        rightEdge[i] = i - maxLength + A[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(leftEdge);
    Arrays.sort(rightEdge);

    int sum = mergeAndCountOverlaps(leftEdge,rightEdge, maxLength);
    return sum;
}
```

The merge routine is a modified merge from a merge sort. It merges two sorted
arrays, keeping the sort order intact and adding in the overlap count functionality. In this case, we do not need to return the merged array, only the overlap count.

```
private int mergeAndCountOverlaps(int[] leftEdge, int [] rightEdge, int maxLength) {
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while ((leftIndex < leftEdge.length) || (rightIndex < rightEdge.length)) {
        if ((leftIndex < leftEdge.length) && (rightIndex < rightEdge.length)) {
            boolean compareLeftEdgeandRightEdge;
            if (leftEdge[leftIndex] < -2147483647 + maxLength) {
                compareLeftEdgeandRightEdge = leftEdge[leftIndex] <= rightEdge[rightIndex] + maxLength;
            } else {
                compareLeftEdgeandRightEdge = leftEdge[leftIndex] - maxLength <= rightEdge[rightIndex];
            }
            if (compareLeftEdgeandRightEdge) {
                // a new left edge
                sum += total;
                if (sum > 10000000) {
                    return -1;
                }
                total++;
                leftIndex++;
            } else {
                // a new right edge
                total--;
                rightIndex++;
            }
        } else if (leftIndex < leftEdge.length) {
            // a new left edge
            sum += total;
            if (sum > 10000000) {
                return -1;
            }
            total++;
            leftIndex++;
        } else if (rightIndex < rightEdge.length) {
            // a new right edge
            total--;
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing: you defined compareTo() but not equals(). TreeSet JavaDoc says: "*the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals*"

Other oddity: I don't understand what is the `edge` field, nor why you set it to `i - A[i]`.

Comment: The edge thing is a little unclear. That field usually represents the left edge of the disc - it's i-A[i] because i is the centre and A[i] is the radius. Will try implementing equals as well, I hadn't thought of that. I thought TreeSet only used compareTo though, with implementing equals being good practice for making the code future-proof.

Comment: If the disks have coordinates on (0, i) (traditionally (x, y) coordinates), then they are vertically aligned, so I don't see why you compute a left edge. Even if that's only a vocabulary thing, I don't see how sorting the circles by their edge position solves the intersection problem (it should be solved on sum of radii being less than the distance between the circles).

Comment: That's true, I suppose I was visualising them as having coordinates (i,0) rather than (0,i). So my leftEdges should really be called bottomEdges. The reason sorting by their edge position could work is that for a given Circle c, it is quick to calculate how many circles have a left edge further left than c's right edge, i.e. are intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same demo in preparation for a programming position.  I didn't get the solution developed in time, and got a terrible score as a result (something in the teens).  However, intrigued with the question, I went ahead and completed it on my own.  Here is my solution:

```
 ============================================================================
 Name        : cFundementalsTest.c
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : Hello World in C, Ansi-style
 ============================================================================
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    int N = 5;
    int A[6] = {1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0 };

        int pos_1, pos_2;
        int total;
        for(pos_1=0;pos_1<=N;pos_1++)
        {
            for(pos_2=pos_1+1;pos_2<=N;pos_2++)
            {
                if(A[pos_1] + A[pos_2] >= abs(pos_1 - pos_2))
                { // they share a common point
                    total++;
                    printf("%d and %d\n",pos_1, pos_2);
                    if(total > 10000000)
                        return(-1);
                }
            }
        }
        printf ("\n\n the total is %d",total);
}
```

and here is the results which look correct:

```
0 and 1
0 and 2
0 and 4
1 and 2
1 and 3
1 and 4
1 and 5
2 and 3
2 and 4
3 and 4
4 and 5

 the total is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

On [Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/number_of_disc_intersections/) you need to solve it using sorting, right? Below is JavaScript solution **passing 100% tests**.

We use two arrays of ranges on axis `x`. Values in both arrays are the same, but first sorted by `from` parameter and second by `to` (both ascending). Then we scan both arrays simultaneously and track overlaps to count distinctive pairs.

You can play with this code in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/keyavek/edit?js,console).

```
function solution(arr) {
  const r1 = arr.map((n, i) => ({from: i - n, to: n + i})).sort((a, b) => a.from - b.from)
  const r2 = r1.slice().sort((a, b) => a.to - b.to)
  let i = 0, j = 0
  let overlaps = 0
  let pairs = 0

  while (i < r1.length || j < r2.length) {
    if (i < r1.length && r1[i].from <= r2[j].to) {
      pairs += overlaps
      if (pairs > 10000000) {
        return -1
      }
      overlaps++
      i++
    } else {
      overlaps--
      j++
    }
  }
  return pairs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        long[] leftpoint=new long[A.length];
        long[] rigthpoint=new long[A.length];
        if(A.length<2)return 0;
    
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;++i){
            leftpoint[i]=-A[i];
            leftpoint[i]+=i;
            rigthpoint[i]=A[i];
            rigthpoint[i]+=i;
        }
        Arrays.sort(leftpoint);
        Arrays.sort(rigthpoint);
        int intersection =0;
        int j=0;
        int i=0;
        int open=0;
        while(i<A.length&&j<A.length){
             if(rigthpoint[i]>=leftpoint[j]){
                   intersection+=open; 
                   open++; 
                   j++;
             }else{
                 open--;
                 i++;
             }
             if(intersection>10000000)return -1;
            }
        return intersection;
    }
}
```

1)Create two arrays one for the left points of the circles and one for the right
2)Sort the arrays
3) Create a variable to keep the number of left points you passed less than the right points you passed(open) and one to ans(intersection) and tow to ran on the array
4)We all have open points that have not closed! For any right point smaller than the left point We have a number of additional intersection as the number of points that have not been closed so we will add them to the answer + (open++;"new open point Because we have reached the new left point") And if we reach a point that closes we remove from the open circles one because one circle will no longer be in the other intersection
**The idea of the algorithm is to notice that each left point is intersected with left points that are only smaller than it so we can only count from the left how many left points are more left than us! It is important to understand that when there is a point that closes a circle one of the circles no longer participates "open--" and therefore still every left point that is larger is subtracted if the number of unclosed circles whose left point is smaller than the point being checked**

Comment: Please [edit] your explanation into your post rather than posting them as comments.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update the post , please note people trying to answer are busy so be to the point as to what you have tried and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code in Python with O(N*LOG(N)) time complexity.

Let describe the logic of the code.

1. I converted the i (center) and A[i] (radius) to the start and end points.

   - start= i-A[i]
   - end= i+A[i]
2. Add points to a list of tuples (start/end point, "open or close state")
3. Sort the list based on start/end (ascending) and "open or close state" (descending). To avoid "close" preceding "open" state in case of radius = 0.
4. From the lowest point to the upper points (left to right in X-axis) start processing and if it is an "open" point add it to the sum of intersects, otherwise, just decrease the number of opened points (total_open).

   ```
   import operator
   def solution(A):
    intersects=0
    n=len(A)
    points=[]
    for i in range(n):
        points.append((i-A[i],"open"))
        points.append((A[i]+i,"close"))

    points.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    points.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    total_open=0
    for i in points:
        if (i[1]=="open"):
            intersects+=total_open
            total_open+=1
        if(i[1]=="close"):
            total_open-=1
        #print("intersects", intersects,"\t Total:",total_open)
    if(intersects>10000000):
        return -1
    return intersects
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Assume j is always bigger than i, to satisfy that two circles interact, the inequality below should always works:

```
|R(i) - R(j)| <= j - i <= R(i) + R(j)
```

That is another way of saying:

```
abs(A[i] - A[j]) <= j - i <= A[i] + A[j]
```

I have not tested, but I think it works.
Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

public int number_of_disc_intersections(int[] A){

    int len = A.length;
    int intersections = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){

        if(A[i] <= 0){
            continue;
        }

        for(int j = i + 1; j < len; j++){

            if(A[j] <= 0){
                continue;       
            }

            if(abs((A[i] - A[j]) <= j - i) && (j - i <= A[i] + A[j])){
                intersections ++;
            }
        }
    }

    return intersections;
}
```

Comment: This has a quadratic runtime.